# Formula with text, good design?

Tags: align, text-manipulation

I have the following text in my align environment, but it does not look good. So what should I change in order to get a better design/output?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     
        12pt,                               
        ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
R_ {t+1}^{simple}=\frac{\text{(asset price at t+1) $ - $ (asset price at t)}}{\text{asset price at t}} \hspace*{0.5cm}r_{t+1}^{log}=ln \left( \frac{\text{asset price at t+1}} {\text{asset price at t}}\right) \hspace*{0.2cm}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably define a notation like $P_t$ and $P_{t+1}$ for prices respectively at $t$ and $t+1$, end your formula with a comma and add “where $P_t$ and $P_{t+1}$ respectively mean …” after the formula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would

1. format textual superscripts with `\textrm`
2. use `\ln` instead of just `ln` (assuming this is a logarithm)
3. use `equation` instead of `align` for a single equation
4. define a variable for the asset price to reduce repeating text.

That gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     
        12pt,                               
        ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Old version:
\begin{align}
R_ {t+1}^{simple}=\frac{\text{(asset price at t+1) $ - $ (asset price at t)}}{\text{asset price at t}} \hspace*{0.5cm}r_{t+1}^{log}=ln \left( \frac{\text{asset price at t+1}} {\text{asset price at t}}\right) \hspace*{0.2cm}
\end{align}

New version:
\begin{equation}
  R_{t+1}^{\textrm{simple}} = \frac{P_{t+1}-P_t}{P_t}
  \qquad
  r_{t+1}^{\textrm{log}} = \ln \left(\frac{P_{t+1}} {P_t}\right),
\end{equation}
where  $P_t$ is the asset price at $t$.
\end{document}
```

and looks like this:
[image: sample output]

Comment: I agree, this is a good recommendation. @mafp, what are you using to make the image?

Comment: @daleif I pulled a rectangle around that stuff in my PDF viewer, and saved it as a png.

Comment: thanks, I usually use dvipng, but it tends to cut stuff of at the edges.

Comment: @mafp and how can I get a space between the two formulas? So that the $r^log_{t+1}$ is a bit more to the right?

Comment: @StatTistician You can use one of the thin spaces, like `\,`.

Comment: I used hspace, which also worked, but thanks!@mafp

Comment: You may want to insert `\quad` or even `\qquad` before `r_{t+1}`.

Comment: Didn't even notice that one, thanks @Mico, I'd recommend `, \quad` or as @Mico mentions even `, \qquad`. I tend to to the first in most of my edits.

Comment: @Mico Wait, are these two different formulas? Then `\qquad` is appropriate. I think I misread that.

Comment: @mafp - The first formula is for percentage returns, and the second is for returns expressed as log first differences. Separating them visually would seem to be important.

Answer (score 0):

You should be more careful with what is math and what is text. I would do something like this

```
R_ {t+1}^{\textup{simple}}=
  \frac{\text{(asset price at $t+1$) $ - $ (asset price at $t$)}}
    {\text{asset price at $t$}} 
\hspace*{0.5cm}
r_{t+1}^{\textup{log}}= 
\operatorname{ln} \left( 
  \frac{\text{asset price at $t+1$}} 
  {\text{asset price at $t$}}
\right)
```

Now all the `t` should look alike. I don't see the point in the last `hspace`